# NSCollectionView get selected item on button click

Tags: cocoa, xcode, cocoa-bindings

I have a `NSCollectionView` is bound to an `NSArrayController` that has an `NSMutableArray` as content. Items in the `NSMutableArray` are displayed as they should.

I have an WindowController class that holds a reference to the `NSMutableArray`. There is also a button that causes a `buttonClicked` message to be sent to my WindowController.

Now inside `buttonClicked` I want to know what item is selected in the `NSCollectionView`. How do I do this? I have no reference to the `NSArrayController` otherwise I could have asked it by sending `selection`. I've studied some sample code but to no avail.

How can I get a reference to the currently selected item in the `NSArrayController`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if the `NSCollectionView` is getting its content from the `NSArrayController`, as there is a binding set in IB on `content` or you have programmatically bound these, there is also a binding available on the collectionView's `selectionIndexes`, which when bound to the arrayController will give you 'a reference to the currently selected item' in the arrayController and the collectionView.

NSCollectionView's itemAtIndex, handed the currently selected item's index, will get you the actual item that is selected.

is the **actual item that is selected** what you are looking to obtain a reference to?

Comment: Thanks for your replay. I realised now how confusing my question must seem :) Your answwer helped me fix this! What I did was I created a `IBOutlet NSArrayController* arrayController` in my WindowController. And then created a connection in the Interface Builder interface. Then I could just send a `selected` message to the array controller to fetch the actual selected item.